# using ffmpeg to capture images from RTSP camera and output to memory instead of disk

Tags: command-line, memory, ffmpeg, images

I want to use ffmpeg command line to capture the images from RTSP camera every second. But I want to store the image into memory instead of the disk so I can further process the image from memory quickly.

I have tried the way as [stream pip method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294919/can-you-stream-images-to-ffmpeg-to-construct-a-video-instead-of-saving-them-t), but I can not capture the image during the middle of the stream.

Currently, I am using the ffmpeg to capture the image into disk as below:

```
ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel 0 -rtsp_transport udp -y -i " +  rtsp_url + " -f image2 -r 1/1 frames/img01d.jpg
```

Currently, in my restricted CPU and memory environment, it takes me several seconds to store the image into the disk and read it into memory, so I am seeking help to see if I can output captured the images into memory.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how relevant this answer will be today (almost 5 years after the question was posted) but I would recommend that you mount a ram disk on your OS (assuming it is Linux/Unix) using this:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk
mount -t tmpfs -o size=2048M tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

Adjust the size to your needs and availability and output the images into the /mnt/ramdisk directory.